# Struts2 Checkbox value with Iterator

Tags: checkbox, struts2, iterator

I am having below code

```html
<s:iterator value="assignedProductRoleBean.serviceProfiles" status="serStatus">
  <tr>
    <td width="150px">
      <s:property value="serviceSpecCode" />
    </td>
    <s:hidden name="assignedProductRoleBean.serviceProfiles[{#serStatus.index}].serviceSpecCode" value="{serviceSpecCode}" />
    <td width="150px">
      <s:property value="code" />
    </td>
    <s:hidden name="assignedProductRoleBean.serviceProfiles[%{#serStatus.index}].code" value="%{code}" />
    <td width="50px">
      <s:checkbox name="assignedProductRoleBean.serviceProfiles[{#serStatus.index}].granted" value="granted" cssStyle="width:20px;border:0;background-color:transparent" />
    </td>
    <s:iterator value="assignedProductRoleBean.serviceProfiles[{#serStatus.index}].characteristics" status="serCharStatus">
      test
      <td width="150px">
        <s:property value="key" />
      </td>
      <s:hidden name="assignedProductRoleBean.serviceProfiles[{#serStatus.index}].characteristics[%{#serCharStatus.index}].key" value="%{key}" />
      <td width="150px">
        <s:textfield theme="simple" name="assignedProductRoleBean.serviceProfiles[%{#serStatus.index}].characteristics[%{#serCharStatus.index}].value" value="%{value}" /></td>
    </s:iterator>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Problem is, I am getting CHECKED view for true values of 'granted'. however When I uncheck/check in view page, they are not getting updated to respective bean.

One more issue with second iterator (inner). I am having characterstics, though they are not getting displayed in jsp page. however after submitting page, they are coming to action class.

ps i even tried value=%{granted}

Comment: I'm not entire sure what you're asking. Also, you might want to make sure the HTML being generated from this is legal, I'm not sure you can put stuff in-between table rows like that, in a reliable way. What type is `granted`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was stuck with the same issue. I've got this working:

```
<div>           
            <s:iterator value="podTypeContentList" status="stat" var="podTypeContent"> 
                <s:if test = "#podTypeContent.selected == true">
                    a
                </s:if>
                <s:else>
                    b
                </s:else>               
                <s:property value="%{podContent}" />
                <s:property value="%{selected}" />  

                <s:checkbox name="%{id}" value="%{selected}"  fieldValue="%{podContent}"  />
                <br />
            </s:iterator>
            <br class="clear" />
            <s:submit align="center" value="Save" id="submitButton" cssClass="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
```

The "selected" is actually isSelected boolean bean property. Threw me off for few hours.